# Google Script: Figuring out how to compare time A between time B and time C

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google script where it's trying to check if a given time A is between time B and time C:
IE:

```
var A = getCurrentSheet.getRange("P30").getDisplayValue();
//08:40:00 AM
var B = getCurrentSheet.getRange("P31").getDisplayValue();
//04:30:00 AM
var C = getCurrentSheet.getRange("P32").getDisplayValue();
//10:40:00 AM
```

The goal is to create a logical comparison where:

```
if(B <= A <= C)
```

Though I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to get the script to recognize these values as time in terms of HH:mm:ss

Comment: Use `getValue()` to get a direct date object instead of converting

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareTimes() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 const [b,a,c] = sh.getRange( 2, 1, 1, 3).getValues().flat().map(e => new Date(e).valueOf());//using Date constructor to get date object and then valueOf() methold to get milliseconds from reference data
 if(b <= a <= c) SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('It is true.');
}
```

active sheet:

| b | a | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/26/2021 01:30:00 | 9/26/2021 02:30:00 | 9/26/2021 03:30:00 |

Dialog:

[image]